# SQL: foreach query result - run query

Tags: mysql, sql, foreach

I have a tableX with items and each item has a category_id and rating.
I want to take the item with the highest rating form each category.

I imagine i have to do something like

`SELECT DISTINCT category_id from tableX;`

Then run a foreach those results with another query like

`SELECT * from tableX where category_id = ${1} ORDER BY rating, LIMIT 1;`

OR something like

`call foreach('SELECT distinct category_id FROM tableX', 'SELECT * from tableX WHERE category_id = ${1} ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 1')`

Edit:

I added some rows examples

```
CREATE TABLE `tableX` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `rating` double(6,1) DEFAULT '0.0',
  `category_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Dumping data for table `tableX`

```
INSERT INTO `tableX` (`id`, `rating`, `category_id`) VALUES
(1463, 8.0, 1),
(1464, 8.0, 1),
(1465, 8.0, 1),
(1466, 9.0, 1),
(1467, 9.0, 1),
(1468, 3.0, 1),
(1469, 8.0, 1),
(1470, 2.0, 1),
(1471, 4.0, 1),
(1472, 9.0, 1),
(1473, 5.0, 1),
(1474, 9.0, 1),
(1475, 10.0, 1),
(1476, 7.0, 1),
(1477, 7.0, 1),
(1478, 6.0, 1),
(1479, 10.0, 1),
(1480, 3.0, 1),
(1481, 7.0, 1),
(1482, 4.0, 1),
(1483, 7.0, 1),
(1484, 4.0, 1),
(1485, 2.0, 1),
(1486, 4.0, 1),
(1487, 5.0, 1),
(1488, 9.0, 1),
(1489, 8.0, 1),
(1490, 7.0, 1),
(1491, 10.0, 1),
(1492, 9.0, 1),
(1493, 9.0, 1),
(1494, 9.0, 2),
(1495, 3.0, 2),
(1496, 9.0, 2),
(1497, 9.0, 2),
(1498, 2.0, 2),
(1499, 4.0, 2),
(1500, 5.0, 2),
(1501, 7.0, 2),
(1502, 5.0, 2),
(1503, 7.0, 2),
(1504, 10.0, 2),
(1505, 6.0, 2),
(1506, 6.0, 4),
(1507, 1.0, 4),
(1508, 5.0, 4),
(1509, 7.0, 5),
(1510, 4.0, 5);
```

Indexes for dumped tables

```
ALTER TABLE `tableX`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `category_id` (`category_id`);
```

Comment: GROUP BY, or similar?

Comment: And what language are you using here, other than SQL

Comment: [mcve] - to make things clearer.

Comment: I will try to provide the table schema and some rows? Let me see - I need to remove the sensitive data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rank()` or `row_number()`:

```
select x.*
from (select x.*,
             row_number() over (partition by category_id order by rating desc) as seqnum
      from tableX x
     ) x
where seqnum = 1;
```

For ties, use `rank()` (that is all rows with the highest  rating).

That above works in MySQL 8+.  In earlier versions, you can use a correlated subquery.  Something like:

```
select x.*
from tableX x
where x.rating = (select max(x2.rating)
                  from tableX x2
                  where x2.category_id = x.category_id
                 );
```

If you want only one row using the second form, then:

```
select x.*
from tableX x
where x.id = (select x2.id
              from tableX x2
              where x2.category_id = x.category_id
              order by x2.rating desc
              limit 1
             );
```

Comment: this returns rows only form the first category. I think you need to add a DISTINCT category_id somewhere

Comment: Ok I see now that your query (the second one which works for me) returns multiple rows from same category_id if they have same max rating. I can skip them manually so your query is the closest so far, thanks.

Comment: @alextoader . . . I added a third version to return only one row using the subquery.